# No match for operator [ ]

Tags: c++, parameters

I'm not sure why I'm getting this message, given that square brackets aren't an operator.

In my `IntSet.h` file, I have declared a particular function that looks like this.

```
IntSet unions(const IntSet& operand)const;
```

The file is called by an `IntSet`, takes another `IntSet` as an argument, and returns the union of the two sets.

In my `IntSet.cpp` file, it looks like this.

```
IntSet IntSet::unions(const IntSet& operand) const
{
    IntSet returnSet(50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        if (setArray[i] == 1 || operand[i]==1){
            if(setArray[i] == 1 ){
                returnSet.addElement(setArray[i]);
            }
            else if(operand[i] == 1){
                returnSet.addElement(operand[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return returnSet;
}
```

The error I'm getting comes from the `operand[I] == 1`.

```
IntSet.cpp|52|error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'const IntSet' and 'int')
```

The program must not override any operators to start. I should also mention that `IntSet unions(const IntSet& operand)const;` was provided and also cannot be changed.

Any direction as to how I should solve this?

Comment: std::set does not have const operator[] overload: user .at() function instead

Comment: You have to overload `IntSet::operator[]` because you want to call `operator[]` on it.

Comment: Operator overloading is not permitted in any form. Nor can I change the class method declaration or parameters.

Comment: @JeffreyDilley you explicitly said that you looked into overloading operators, now you tell us it's not allowed. Voting to close this question because we can't wait and give answers just for you to successively reveal game-changing info. Ask a complete question.

Comment: "Regardless, the program must not override and operators to start" was posted in the original question. I'm asking about the errors, given that I can not override operator.

Comment: is `setArray` a member variable?

Comment: @StoryTeller, yes, private class variable.

Comment: @JeffreyDilley so if this is a central restraint, why isn't it in there anymore? And even so, if you mustn't implement something, why do you still use it?! Totally zero-value question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `setArray` is a member variable of `IntSet`, and you cannot overload `operator[]` for `IntSet`, then your access of `operand[i]` should probably be `operand.setArray[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

> I looked into overloading operators, but the square brackets don't seem to be overloadable.

They most definitely are!

So this sentence of yours implies your `IntSet` class doesn't have a `[]` brackets operator, yet you use it. The error message says exactly that; so there's your problem.

Comment: Operator overloading is not permitted in any form :/

Comment: @JeffreyDilley what?! That makes no sense at all. Are you programming C++ or not?

Comment: Restrictions on this particular code. It's a small piece of a much larger project i'm working on for a Discrete Mathematics course.

Comment: @JeffreyDilley a) that's still pure bullshit. Please say hello to whoever defines these arbitrary restraints. If you do C++, allow operator overloading. b) You can't just add "oh and there's this and that restriction on code" later on.

Comment: It was in the original post! Check the edits. I'm sorry you skimmed over that very important line. All I did was edit out the useless part about overriding, which was a mistake to include in the first place. Apologies.

Comment: What's useless about including crucial info like "I mustn't do what I try to do"?!

Answer (score 1):

You must have 'forgotten' to overload the `IntSet::operator[](int) const`. Simply add that to your class definition:

```
class IntSet {
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> buffer;
/* ... */
public:
  int& operator[](int i) { return buffer[i]; }
  int  operator[](int i) const { return buffer[i]; }
};
```

Note that I'm guessing about the innards of your class `IntSet` since you have failed to provide any details.

---

If your task does not allow you to overload operators, then you must use those provided by the language or standard library. In the context of my code snippet above, this would mean to use the buffer's `operator[]` directly as in `operand.buffer[i]` (you may need to make `buffer` a `public` member if access from non-members is required).

Comment: I'm just wondering, should I have included the entire .h file and the .cpp file? They are quite long, and I felt like I posted the important bits of information. What would be helpful to include on a question like this?

Comment: You should have included those parts of your .h and .cpp file which are required to reproduce your problem, nothing less and nothing more. This includes reducing the definition of all relevant classes to the bare minimum required.

Comment: Why make it public? It's accessible in a member function?